# using overloaded operator[]

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm trying to use an overloaded operator, but not sure how could i use/call it in my main cpp. the code is in an other file and looks like this:

```
string postH::operator[](int add){
   if(add > 100)
   {return "\nsome text\n";}
    else {return "\nsome other text\n";}
   }
```

Comment: Which makes me wonder why you did overload it at all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use it like normal array indexing.

```
postH foo;
std::cout << foo[150];
```

Comment: thx it worked:) made it like this just didn't knew it needs cout in front:)

Comment: @JánosBalázs it *doesn't* need `cout` in front.

Answer (score 1):

operator `[]` gets an integer value between the braces. that's why you should give a parameter in your overloading function. After that you can use the operator as usual: `postHObj[10]`
In other words 10 is the `add`
I think [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/98-overloading-the-subscript-operator/) will be helpful

Comment: i tryed like this :
post1[felad1.getCS_Suly()]; (note: the felad1.getCS_Suly() gives an int)
but this way it's not working.
//made it thx:)